# Adding time estimates for each file in progress upload

Tags: fine-uploader

I have a requirement to show time estimates for each file currently in progress of being uploaded.  We are testing out the UI portion of the uploader and wondered if there is a way to add this in near the current % complete/size information that is currently displayed.

I don't really want to make my own entire custom UI just for that purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom elements to Fine Uploader's template, and these elements will be rendered onto the DOM which you can than manipulate via JavaScript.

```html
<script type="text/template" id="qq-template">
    <div class="qq-uploader-selector qq-uploader">
        ...
       <ul class="qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list">
            <li>
                ...
                <!-- custom element for updating with progress -->
                <span class="file-progress"></span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    ...
    </div>
</script>
```

You would then have to tie into Fine Uploader's events to update that element when the file is submitted ([onSubmitted](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#submitted)) or progresses ([onProgress](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#progress)). To do this you'd use the [`getItemByFileId`](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#getItemByFileId) API method to select the file list item in the DOM, and then use JS to select that child element containing the progress element that you wanted to update, and -- naturally -- update it as you would.

```js
// ...

onSubmitted: function (id, name) {
    var el = getElementByFileId(id) // retrieves the list element for this file id.
    // initialze the progress element, with 0% for example
},

// ...

onProgress: function (id, name, uploadedBytes, totalBytes) {
    // update as the file progresses ....
}

// ...
```

The [documentation](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/styling.html#include-other-custom-elements-in-your-template) has more examples on how easy it is to add custom elements to the DOM.

Comment: Perfect...for some reason I missed that part of the Styling page...I swear I looked it over first :-(  Thanks.

Comment: also a heads up, your example  html "<span class="file-progress"></a>"  should close with a span, not an anchor tag.